# Как установить взаимосвязь между кнопками и элементами в списке?(Python, tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

Думаю, что вопрос достаточно глупый, но что-то я уже долго не могу придумать решение. Даже не представляю, как такое загуглить. У меня в коде на Python есть список. К каждому значению из этого списка создается кнопка с помощью модуля tkinter. При нажатии на кнопку мне нужно вызывать функцию, которая примет в качестве аргумента значение из списка, которое должно быть как-то привязано к этой выбранной кнопке. Я начал писать код и почему-то не подумал, что предусмотрел не все. Если что, вот он:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.minsize(200, 200)

numbers = [1, 2, 3]

def cmd(num):
    print(str(num))

for num in numbers:
    button = Button(root,
                    text = 'Button' + str(num),
                    command = cmd)
    button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, каким образом мне установить взаимосвязь между кнопкой и значением из словаря?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.minsize(200, 200)

numbers = [1, 2, 3]

def cmd(num):
    print(str(num))

# Добавьте эту функцию
def func_generator(num):
    def cmd_with_num():
        return cmd(num)
    return cmd_with_num

for num in numbers:
    button = Button(root,
                    text = 'Button' + str(num),
                    command = func_generator(num))  # И напишите так
    button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Смысл в том, что вам нужно передавать в `command` функцию, которая не имеет аргументов, а уже содержит все нужные значения в себе.

Этого можно добиться, сделав функцию, которая будет возвращать другую функцию с нужными значениями внутри.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Более простой вариант с использованием lambda:

```
command = lambda num=num: cmd(num)
```

Версия подсмотрена здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677649/tkinter-assign-button-command-in-loop-with-lambda

Comment: Огромное спасибо!